# Why my Test class is not entering 'for loop'?

Tags: trigger, unit-test

This is My Trigger for finding duplicate for **Phone** And **MobilePhone**

```
trigger duplicate_mobile on Contact (before insert, before update) {

      Map<String,Contact> mapContact = new Map<String,Contact>();

      for(Contact cont :Trigger.new){
        if((cont.phone != null ) && (System.Trigger.isInsert) ||(cont.phone != System.trigger.oldmap.get(cont.Id).phone)){

            mapcontact.put(cont.phone,cont);
                         }
        if((cont.MobilePhone!= null) && (system.trigger.isInsert) ||(cont.MobilePhone!= system.trigger.oldmap.get(cont.id).MobilePhone)){

          mapcontact.put(cont.MobilePhone,cont); 
      }

     }

     for(contact cont :[select phone from contact where phone in:mapcontact.keyset()]){

         contact cc =  mapcontact.get(cont.phone);
         cc.phone.adderror('error');                                              
         }

         for(contact con :[select MobilePhone from contact where MobilePhone in:mapcontact.keyset()]){
            contact ccc = mapcontact.get(con.MobilePhone);
            ccc.MobilePhone.adderror('error already no is saved');
         }
     }
```

This is my unit test

```
@isTest
//test methos for duplicate_mobile for contact
private class test_duplicate_mobile{
static testmethod void dup_phone(){
contact contw = new contact ();
    contw.lastname = 'tester';
    contw.phone = '9999999999';
    contw.mobilephone = '8888888888';
    insert contw;

    contact contr = new contact();
    contr.lastname='as';
    contr.phone = '7777777777';
    contr.mobilephone='0000000000';
    insert contr;

    contw.phone = '11111111111';
    contw.mobilephone = '8888888887';
    update contw;
}
}
```

I am getting 66% code coverage because it is not entering for loops
 this is snapshot of code coverage

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not entering the loop because the queries don't return any records. As far as I can tell, the purpose is to detect duplicate phone numbers, but you're not inserting duplicate phone numbers in your test.

Try adding this to your test:

```
contact contr = new contact();
contr.lastname='as';
contr.phone = '9999999999';
contr.mobilephone='8888888888';
insert contr;
```

Comment: Thanks, for code. Now I am getting 100% test coverage,but it is not passing the method, Error is "System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, error already no is saved: [MobilePhone]"

Comment: That's what you wanted right? To test the validation. So enclose the insert I gave you in a try-catch and assert the message.